# Strange behavior usiung QGIS Vertex Tool

Tags: qgis, editing

I had to manually examine a polygon shapefile with > 16000 features and edit them if necessary. For this, I use the `Vertex Tool`. While editing, these blue transparent lines (see image 1) appear. If I click on them, the rubberband line leads to a feature lying far away (see image 2).
[image] [image]

What are these "ghost features"? Maybe these are features with areas of `0`? I have never come across this behaviour.

Comment: I guess there is a problem related to the projection settings: Check if the vector CRS and the project CRS is the same and try again.

Comment: both are set to epsg 32633 WGS84/UTM zone 33N